# DirectX 12 application is crashing in Windows 11

Tags: directx-12, windows-11, directxtk

I'm quite a ways into a DirectX 12 desktop x64 application built upon several of the DirectX Tool Kit examples, but now also supports custom shaders for directional and omnidirectional shadows, dynamic reflections, a hardware-instanced particle effect system, FBX model skeletal animation, and depth of field post-processing.

On Halloween, Windows Update upgraded my system (Intel Core i7[8th Gen]/GeForce GTX1050) to Windows 11. When I ran my project, I received a spooky surprise in the form of the following 'Source Not Available' window:

[image]

After stopping the debug, the application was crashing at the `Present()` call in *DeviceResources.cpp* and generating the following error:

```
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandQueue::Present: Resource state (0x800: D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE) (promoted from COMMON state) of resource (0x0000011BD5330080:'Render target 0') (subresource: 0) must be in COMMON state when transitioning to use in a different Command List type, because resource state on previous Command List type : D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY, is actually incompatible and different from that on the next Command List type : D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #990: RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE]
D3D12: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ ERROR RESOURCE_MANIPULATION #990: RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE ]
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA0F6A466C (KernelBase.dll) in DXTK12 Game.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000014297FC640, 0x00000014297FE420).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA0F6A466C (KernelBase.dll) in DXTK12 Game.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000014297FC640, 0x00000014297FE420).
```

This never occurred in Windows 10 and what's more, this crash is unstable. My game is configured to start in borderless fullscreen mode, and can sometimes run for a few seconds before crashing. If I have time to Alt+Enter to windowed mode, the app will still crash.

I've updated my Nvidia driver and have pointed the project to the latest Windows 11 SDK version (10.0.22000.0) but the problem persists.

After some googling, there's evidence to suggest there's a known issue concerning erratic DXGI/WDM behaviour on Windows 11 that's been reported by users running games in emulated fullscreen (i.e. borderless windowed) mode. I was also experiencing faulty Alt+Tab window switching behaviour following a crash, but this seems to have been fixed by the graphics driver update.

Have any other developers been experiencing stability and/or performance issues with DirectX 12 on Windows 11? Or should I just sit tight and wait for future Windows updates to stabilise the new OS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in the DXGI Debug Layer interaction with the DX12 Debug Layer w/ Windows 11. There's a simple workaround which is to suppress `D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE`. The bug itself will be fixed in a future Windows update.

The Debug Layer has always had quirks when it comes to dealing with 'hybrid graphics' systems (i.e. laptops with both Intel Integrated and discrete GPUs), so I have a few suppressions in the DeviceResources implementation related to it:

```
DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_ID hide[] =
{
    80 /* IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput: The swapchain's adapter does not control the output on which the swapchain's window resides. */,
};
DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter = {};
filter.DenyList.NumIDs = static_cast<UINT>(std::size(hide));
filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
dxgiInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(DXGI_DEBUG_DXGI, &filter);
```

```
D3D12_MESSAGE_ID hide[] =
{
    D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_MAP_INVALID_NULLRANGE,
    D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_UNMAP_INVALID_NULLRANGE,
    // Workarounds for debug layer issues on hybrid-graphics systems
    D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_EXECUTECOMMANDLISTS_WRONGSWAPCHAINBUFFERREFERENCE,
    D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE,
};
D3D12_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter = {};
filter.DenyList.NumIDs = static_cast<UINT>(std::size(hide));
filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
d3dInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
```

The workaround is included in the [October 2021](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/releases) release of my Direct3D Game template VSIX.  See [this commit](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/commit/2b34dcf9ac764153699058cdc9d4dbc4e837224c)

> The `D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_EXECUTECOMMANDLISTS_WRONGSWAPCHAINBUFFERREFERENCE` error can trigger during "lost device" handling on hybrid-graphics systems. This issue was introduced in Windows 10 (18363). It should be fixed now, so in theory you can remove that suppression for Windows 11. Added suppression in [this commit](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/commit/f6347602b0900a5e3a6a657462c47ce6cbb4926d).

> The "IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput" DXGI warning was introduced in Windows 10 (17134). Added suppression in [this commit](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/commit/18e3eaa444e98ba75d37d506ab18df8db0b82441).

Comment: Thank you @ChuckWalbourn. I can report that after adding D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE to the D3D12_MESSAGE_ID enum list, my game runs perfectly in Windows 11. Thanks again for your work on the DirectXTK, which for DirectX 12 is invaluable. The best feature IMO is the GraphicsResource memory allocator helper, which replaces the hassle of setting up a circular frame resources buffer for 'in-flight' constant buffer data (as required in 'raw' DirectX 12 programming), among other benefits such as managing GPU fencing for you as well. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. It seems several examples from Frank Luna's 2016 Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12 broke.. reviving some of the compute shader examples, I found the following spooks.. just add them to the hidden list to stop some silly console  reports in VS 
D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_RESOURCE_BARRIER_BEFORE_AFTER_MISMATCH, (WaveCS) D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_COMMAND_LIST_DRAW_VERTEX_BUFFER_NOT_SET (Sobel)   D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_CLEARRENDERTARGETVIEW_MISMATCHINGCLEARVALUE (Sobel) Note:I don't know if I can safely switch them off elsewhere..