# Why am I getting an unhandled exception in KernelBase.dll when I'm trying to call ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource method?

Tags: c++, directx-12

I am trying to setup a DX12 renderer and to upload the vertex data to the GPU using the UpdateBufferResource function as mentioned below. In the CreateCommittedResource call it throws unhandled exception message. I can continue through the exception but I don't know what is causing this to pop up. I have built the project using CMake 3.24.0 and VS 2022.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF69654FFC (KernelBase.dll) in Tutorial2.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000001291FDBED0, 0x0000001291FDDCA0).
```

```
void Tutorial2::UpdateBufferResource(
    ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList2> commandList,
    ID3D12Resource** pDestinationResource,
    ID3D12Resource** pIntermediateResource,
    size_t numElements, size_t elementSize, const void* bufferData,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAGS flags)
{
    //ID3D12Device2
    auto device = Application::Get().GetDevice();

    size_t bufferSize = numElements * elementSize;

    // Create a committed resource for the GPU resource in a default heap.
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(bufferSize, flags),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(pDestinationResource)));

    // Some more bufferData upload....

}
```

I am able to continue through the exception but it happens every time CreateCommittedResource is called

[Call Stack and Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCSlV.png)

Trying to upload the vertex information to the GPU to render a cube. The HRESULT of the CreateCommittedResource is S_OK as well. But I am not sure what this unhandled exception means and how to resolve it

Comment: Is there any related output in the debug output window? I suspect (though I might be wrong) you already have the debug layer enabled and set it to break on error/warning and there is an error in the output window that states more about what's wrong. If that's not the case then you should enable the debug layer and see if there's an error then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805245/directx-12-application-is-crashing-in-windows-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254352/carsten)'s comment above, you are likely seeing the following in the Output window:

```
D3D12 WARNING: ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource: Ignoring InitialState D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST. Buffers are effectively created in state D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #1328: CREATERESOURCE_STATE_IGNORED]
D3D12: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ WARNING STATE_CREATION #1328: CREATERESOURCE_STATE_IGNORED ]
```

This is triggered by the `ID3D12InfoQueue` likely created in your Debug build.  To prevent this instance from triggering an exception, add the following to the InfoQueue denied IDs, such as:

```
D3D12_MESSAGE_ID denyIDs[] = {
    D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_CREATERESOURCE_STATE_IGNORED,                  // This triggers a break exception during the first call to CreateCommittedResource.
};
```